# How to put Article inside WebPage element?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

So I have a `WebPage` and inside that `WebPage` I have an `Article`.
Now I know it is not a problem, but when I use this tool:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/

I get some note that the `WebPage` has no elements such as `name` and `description`, in that case what should I do? Should ignore it? Because even if I set meta tags for name and description it will be 100% the same as the `Article` one and then it might double content or doubled values, what should I do?

Example of my page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"> HERE COME THE NAVIGATION CODE 
    </nav>

    <main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Name</h1>
    <p itemprop="description">Description</p>
    </main>

    <div id="some-links">
             <ul>
              <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href="" class="active"><span class="icon icon-eye"></span> Cat Overview</a></li>
              <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href=""><span class="icon icon-dog"></span> Cat Breeds</a></li>
              <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href=""><span class="icon icon-article"></span> Cat Articles</a></li>
              <li><a itemprop="relatedLink" href=""><span class="icon icon-paw"></span> Cat Adoption</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebPage` is *not* empty. It has 5 `relatedLink` properties. But even if it were empty, it would not be a problem.

The `name` for `WebPage` could be the value of your `title` element (e.g., typically including the page *and* the site name), while the `name` of the `Article` could be the value of the page heading (e.g., typically without site name).

You could link the `SiteNavigationElement` with the `WebPage` item (currently both are top-level items, not related to each other), for example with the [`hasPart` property](http://schema.org/hasPart):

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <nav itemprop="hasPart" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"></nav>
</body>
```

I guess the same property could be used to link the `WebPage` with the `Article`. Unfortunately, Schema.org lacks a property for denoting the main content/item of a `WebPage` ([`mainContentOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) can’t be used).

Comment: My question is how search engine will read it? as Article and take the information about WordCount and so on or as a webpage? or maybe both?

Comment: @MyLibary: Discussing the behaviour of search engine services (or SEO) is off-topic on Stack Overflow (as such things can hardly be proved, are often opinion-based, change frequently etc.). A consumer (e.g. a search engine) parsing your document learns that there is information about a `WebPage` and an `Article`. If you use a property like `hasPart`, the consumer also learns that the `Article` is part of the `WebPage`. What consumers make of this information is entirely up to them.

Comment: OK i'm sorry, thanks for your criticism. so i better make article section as also "itemprop="hasPart" ? thanks a lot for your dedicated help.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<html>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article"/>
        <h2 itemprop="headline">Article headline</h2>
        <h3 itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
            By <span itemprop="name">John Doe</span>
        </h3>
        <span itemprop="description">A most wonderful article</span>
        <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <img src="https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg"/>
            <meta itemprop="url" content="https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg">
            <meta itemprop="width" content="800">
            <meta itemprop="height" content="800">
        </div>
        <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
            <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <img src="https://google.com/logo.jpg"/>
                <meta itemprop="url" content="https://google.com/logo.jpg">
                <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Google">
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00"/>
        <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00"/>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

source [one](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466028/how-to-implement-mainentityofpage-to-this-specific-site/34467088#34467088)