# How to implement "mainEntityOfPage" to this specific site?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

Please take a look here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=https%253A%252F%252Fglamourina.net%252Fen%252F

How can I correctly add `mainEntityOfPage` to this site?

In Google documentation example I see something like this:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">

  <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article"/>
```

But this is a single author blog. And it features blogPosts.

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting" class="singlearticles">
```

Would it be good if I change it like this:

```html
<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://linktoarticle"/>
```

Not sure if I understand well the `mainEntityOfPage` usage. I would appreciate if someone can suggest how can I do to this specific case/website. Not generically, because each site can have a different `mainEntityOfPage`, but I need to know and understand the right implementation for this site.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### About Google’s Microdata example

Google’s Microdata example is invalid. If the `meta` element has the `itemprop` attribute, the `content` attribute is required ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22415563/1591669)).

I described [different ways how to specify `mainEntityOfPage` in Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117597/1591669), the most straigtforward one being a `link` element that creates a URL value (instead of another Microdata item):

```html
<link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://example.com/article-1" />
```

#### `mainEntity`

It’s easier to understand the use of [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) if we first look its inverse property, [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity).

For a `WebPage` that contains a `BlogPosting`, we could have:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  </article>
</body>
```

This means: There’s a `WebPage` and a `BlogPosting`, and the `BlogPosting` is the "primary entity" described in this `WebPage`. To denote this especially makes sense if there are more items involved, e.g., a `Person` describing the author, five more `BlogPosting` items for related posts, a `WebSite` item giving some metadata, etc. Thanks to `mainEntity`/`mainEntityOfPage`, consumers can learn what the primary/main item on that page is (i.e., what the page stands for).

#### `mainEntityOfPage`

The following example with `mainEntityOfPage` would result in equivalent structured data like the example with `mainEntity` from above:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  </div>
</article>
```

As you can see, the element for the `BlogPosting` item contains the element for the `WebPage` item. This is of course rather unusual markup.

But the [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) property does not only expect an (`CreativeWork`) item as value, it alternatively expects a URL. So instead of providing a `WebPage` item explicitly, you can provide the URL of the page instead:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://example.com/article-1" />
</article>
```

(This is what Google expects, according to their documentation for the [Articles Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles).)

#### Excursus: URL of page vs. post

Many sites don’t differentiate between the URL for the web page and the URL for the blog post. For these sites it might seem silly to state something like

```
http://example.com/article-1 (the blog post)
is the 'mainEntityOfPage' 
http://example.com/article-1 (the web page)
```

```
http://example.com/article-1 (the web page) 
has 'mainEntity' 
http://example.com/article-1 (the blog post)
```

But it can be useful anyway (e.g., for choosing which item is the primary one, because the other items won’t have this statement; or for a blank node; etc.).

However, some sites do differentiate (especially for [Linked Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23633409/1591669)), so they might state something like

```
http://example.com/article-1#this (the blog post)
is the 'mainEntityOfPage' 
http://example.com/article-1 (the web page)
```

```
http://example.com/article-1 (the web page) 
has 'mainEntity' 
http://example.com/article-1#this (the blog post)
```

Here, `http://example.com/article-1#this` represents the blog posting, and `http://example.com/article-1` represents the page with information about this posting (or the content of the posting itself). A clearer example would be a person and a page about this person; or a building and a page about this building. See my answer for an example [why you might want to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669). (But, as explained above, you don’t have to differentiate; you can use the same URL for both.)

Comment: Thank you for all these details. What about my specific example? There I have `<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">` Should I remove `itemprop="blogPost"` from that and create something like this: `<article itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
   <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://linktoarticle" />`

Comment: @Pikk: No need to remove `blogPost` (and the parent `Blog` item). Especially thanks to `mainEntityOfPage`, having these other types is not problematic. You can give each `BlogPosting` the `link` element with `mainEntityOfPage` (pointing to the URL for the page that contains only this blog post).

Comment: So you are saying that it's good to have two itemprop in the same section and have it like this: `<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting"> <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="https://linktoarticle" />` ?

Comment: @Pikk: Sure. It’s not different to having, for example, `<h1 itemprop="name">Foo</h1>` in the `BlogPosting` item. Each item (created via `itemscope`) has its own properties. Your `Blog` item has the property `blogPost`, your `BlogPosting` item has the property `mainEntityOfPage`.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated

Comment: See if http://www.seoskeptic.com/how-to-use-schema-org-v2-0s-mainentityofpage-property/ makes any sense. What solution did you use in the end? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Respect for the properly validating `<link  itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"...` instead of the Google suggested `<meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"...`

Comment: @AndreBulatov: `meta content` is not intended for links. `link href` is intended for links. Adding an absolute url to the `content` attribute of a `meta` tag will error on the Yandex microdata testing tool whereas a `link` will not, because it's more semantic.