# How to use mainEntityOfPage

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Schema.org explains `mainEntityOfPage` and gives examples here: https://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage

Then Google does in a different way and they give no explanation:
[Google Markup](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles)

I have a blog post in a page, the simplified case is this:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="headline name">Title of the post</h1>
  <div itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-07"></div>
  <div itemprop="articleBody">This is the body of the post</div>
  <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <p itemprop="name">John Doe</p>
  </div>    
</article>
```

In that page, there is only the blog post. How to put `mainEntityOfPage` applied in the example code I give? Can you explain it, please?

I suppose that I have to put, is that correct?:

```
<link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="link-to-this-page">
```

But I have some questions:

- Should this line of code be just below the itemscope itemtype?
- Only to understand the concept, the "Entity" of the page is the classification that Schema.org gives? In my example, the Entity is `BlogPosting`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement "mainEntityOfPage" to this specific site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466028/how-to-implement-mainentityofpage-to-this-specific-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [my answer to *How to implement “mainEntityOfPage” to this specific site?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467088/1591669), this (the `link` element) is one way to implement it, yes. And yes, in your case this element has to be a descendant of the `BlogPosting` item (and not of another item in that item, like `Person`).

Every item (created by an element with `itemscope` attribute) is an *entity*. If you have

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="http://example.com/foo" />
</article>
```

it means that this `BlogPosting` item is the  primary entity of the page identified by the URL `http://example.com/foo`.