# What is the correct use of mainEntityOfPage schema

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I am writing structured data for a magazine. I got this under the Article type:

```
"mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": " https://www.example.com/category" //category of the article
  },
```

I thought I would mark the category of the article using this. Is this the correct way of using `mainEntityOfPage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the value should be the `WebPage` dedicated to the `Article`. Both items would typically have the same `url`, but possibly different `@id` values (see [URL of page vs. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467088/1591669)).

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "@id": "/articles/42#this",
  "url": "/articles/42",

  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "ItemPage",
    "@id": "/articles/42",
    "url": "/articles/42"
  }

}
```

It might become clearer when looking at the inverse property [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity). You would have a `WebPage` for the current page and provide the `mainEntity` property to convey what the primary entity on this page is:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemPage",

    "mainEntity": {
      "@type": "Article"
    }

}
```

When using `mainEntityOfPage` instead of `mainEntity`, you simply switch subject and object.

Comment: In the 1st code snippet you provided, is the '@id' required, if it's a leaf?

Comment: @Ethan: It’s never required. It’s "just" a good practice to provide `@id` for every item, as it allows others to say something about this item ([Linked Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) / [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web)).

Comment: Thanks for answering and the links.